# Dynamically generated Wordpress Wysiwyg Editor ( wp_editor ) not displaying properly

Tags: php, ajax, tinymce, wordpress

I have 2 html wysiwyg editors on a wordpress admin page. Both use WP_EDITOR() function. The first one is hard coded into the page:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="" style="display:block;">
  <p>
    <!-- editor here -->
    <?php
       wp_editor( 'CONTENT WILL APPEAR HERE!', 'addsometxt', array('textarea_name'=>'create_txt','textarea_rows'=>10,'wpautop'=>false));
    ?>
  </p>
  <p>
   <input name="save" type="submit" class="button-primary" id="save" style="margin:5px;" value="Save Input" /></p>
</form>
```

The second one is generated dynamically with a PHP function using an AJAX call (wp_ajax_ and $.post). I've test the ajax call and know it works; so, for brevity, here's the php function:

```
<?php
function display_editor2() {
// grab data from database (data_from_db) and display in editor
  wp_editor( $row->data_from_db, 'editsometxt', array('textarea_name'=>'edit_txt','textarea_rows'=>10,'wpautop'=>false));

} 
?>
```

The problem is that even though the 2nd editor is displaying; it's missing all the tool bar buttons. See image below for illustration. Anyone know who to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I spent WEEKS trying to get wp_editor() to call correctly via AJAX and I STILL don't know how it's done properly. It came with all sorts of wonderful issues. I'd give up whilst you're still ahead if I were you - try a different method that doesn't require wp_editor() and Ajax.

Comment: @Joe Buckle -- LOL! Yeah, situation seems grim. Probably going to have to hack into tinymce. In my research, I found some possible solutions: Kathy Is Awesome's tut here - http://tinyurl.com/ovu2x89

Aforementioned is based on Dimas Begunoff's tut here (which uses his WPAlchemy Metaboxes): http://tinyurl.com/cp55h3d

Closest solution to fit my needs was on this next link, but I couldn't get it to work: http://tinyurl.com/kkdmlkk

Comment: I went through all those links as well. When I'm back in the office in the morning I'll reflect on my methods. I built a plugins that dynamically added full featured editors but not in this way. Bare with me

Comment: No solution to this yet? :( I came with a similar issue while using Handlebars and a popup dialog to display the RTE. Still no working solution :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347099/wordpress-default-rte-editor-in-popup-dialogs-through-templating-system

Comment: @diosney -- Actually, I took a close look at the solution here and got it to work: http://tinyurl.com/obah2eq. Only problem I had was that the QuickTags still weren't displaying. In the end, I opted for a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

When I add the code `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in my footer.php, it works.

Comment: @Markus Read properly. He also provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and solved it this way (WP 4.7):

First create an hidden editor in your template so WP load all the necessary files for TinyMCE (the ID doesn't matter):

```
<div style="display:none"><?php wp_editor('', 'hidden_editor'); ?></div>
```

Then after you appended the new editor to the DOM, use the following functions:

```
quicktags({id :'your_new_editor_id'});
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'your_new_editor_id');
```

Using `tinymce.init` didn't worked for me, as the new editor ID wasn't recognized. Those two lines reinstantiate the quicktags and add the new editor.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/)

```
wp_editor( string $content, string $editor_id, array $settings = array() )
```

the problem is that you are using the same `$editor_id` for both editors , `editsometxt`, try to change it for the second

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to add **media_buttons** and **tinymce** parameter on your AJAX call.

Something like this:

```
<?php
function display_editor2() {
    // grab data from database (data_from_db) and display in editor
    wp_editor( $row->data_from_db, 'editsometxt', array('textarea_name'=>'edit_txt','media_buttons'=>true,'tinymce'=>true,'textarea_rows'=>10,'wpautop'=>false));

    } 
?>
```

I recommend you check [wp_editor()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) Function Reference page at Wordpress Codex.

Comment: 'media_buttons' is true by default. It controls the 'Upload/Insert' text and icon, not the buttons I'm referring to.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I too had the same problem!

I just deactivated all the plug-ins which are installed by me and refreshed the page, and then I tried to edit the post/pages in the visual area also. Check once it will work for you. :)

Answer (score -3):

I hade the same problem, using this:

```
<?php wp_editor(get_the_content()); ?>
```

By passing a ID (second parameter to wp_editor) I got the buttons.
Like this:

```
<?php wp_editor(get_the_content(), "with_a_ID_its_buttons_are_showing"); ?>
```